# Registration form using javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have asked this question before this but the problem is not solved In my code below I am using javascript and php for building registration form. There are two files `register.php` that contains html code for form, javascript library and javascript code. Second file `reghand.php` handles php code for validation and inserting data. Data is inserted correctly into database after form validation but problem appears when validation fails. It's like no javascript comes into action, when validation fails I get redirected to reghand.php where validation errors are shown `{"username":"inuse","password":"missmatch"}` these are errors from my `reghand.php` but I want to use javascript error message that's on `register.php` and that too should appear on the form page itself, not on `reghand.php` Please help.

`register.php`

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
  $("form.register").change(function() {
    $.post("register.php", $("form.register").serialize(), function( data ) {
      if( data.flname == "cntbempty" )
        $("p#name_error").slideDown();
      else
        $("p#name_error").hide();
      if( data.username == "inuse" )
        $("p#username_error").slideDown();
      else
        $("p#username_error").hide();
      if( data.password == "missmatch" )
        $("p#password_error").slideDown();
      else
        $("p#password_error").hide();
      if( data.email == "notvalid" )
        $("p#email_error").slideDown();
      else
        $("p#email_error").hide();
    }, "json");
  });
});
</script>
   <form action="reghand.php" method="post" class="register">
   <fieldset>
   <legend>Registration</legend>
   <input type="text" name="fname" required="required" maxlength="15" placeholder="First Name"/>        
   <input type="text" name="lname" required="required" maxlength="15" placeholder="Last Name"/>
   <p id="name_error" class="error">First name Last name cannot be empty and can be same</p>
   <input type="text" name="username" required="required" maxlength="15" placeholder="Username" class="username" />        
   <p id="username_error" class="error">That Username is unavailable</p>       
   <input type="email" name="email" required="required" maxlength="35" placeholder="Email"/>        
   <p id="email_error" class="error">That Email is already registered</p>       
   <input type="password" name="password" required="required" maxlength="15" placeholder="Password"/>        
   <input type="password" name="password2" required="required" maxlength="15" placeholder="Confirm Password"/>
   <p id="password_error" class="error">Passwords do not match</p>
   <input type="submit" name="reg" value="Sign Up!">
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

`reghand.php`

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['reg'])){
 $fn = ucfirst($_POST['fname']);
 $ln = ucfirst($_POST['lname']);
 $un = $_POST['username'];
 $em = $_POST['email'];
 $pswd = $_POST['password'];
 $pswd2 = $_POST['password2'];
 $sql=$db->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username");
 $sql->execute(array(':username'=>$un));
 $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $db_username = $row['username'];
 $usernames = $db_username;
 $data = array();
 if( isset($fn) && isset($ln) ) {
  if( $fn != "" && $ln!="" && $fn == $ln ) {
    $data["flname"] = "cntbempty";
   }
  }
 if( isset($un) ) {
  if ($un == $usernames )  {
    $data["username"] = "inuse";
   }
  }
 if( isset($pswd) && isset($pswd2) ) {
  if( $pswd2 != "" && $pswd != $pswd2 ) {
    $data["password"] = "missmatch";
   }
  }
  if( isset( $em ) ) {
   if( $em != "" && !preg_match( "/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST["email"] ) ) {
     $data["email"] = "notvalid";
   }
  }
 if(!empty($data))
 {
 echo json_encode($data);
 die;
 }
  else{
  $pswd = password_hash($pswd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
  $pswd2 = password_hash($pswd2, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
  $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username,first_name,last_name,email,password,password2) VALUES (:username,:first_name,:last_name,:email,:password,:password2)");  
  $stmt->execute( array(':username'=>$un,':first_name'=>$fn,':last_name'=>$ln,':email'=>$em,':password'=>$pswd,':password2'=>$pswd2));
  }
  if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
    header("Location: login.php");
  } 
  else {
    echo "error";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: it's a typo/syntax error. had you bothered checking for errors.....................

Comment: you can use $("form.register").submit(function(e) {  e.preventDefault();  // rest your code   });

Comment: why was this upvoted?

Comment: Just out of interest! Why are you hashing the password2 which is the `Confirm Password`? Also why are you storing it on the database? DUH" Thats there just so you can check the user didnt keyin 2 different password i.e. make a keying mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I would prevent submit button from sending form:

```
  jQuery("#submit").click(function(event)
  {
    event.preventDefault(); // cancel default behavior

  });
```

validate fields in javascript and then if all fields are correct submit the form like this:

```
jQuery('#form').submit();
```

Of course you should run second validation of fields in php aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring all the other errors, you have a syntax error in your query!

You should be getting an error from this line

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users 
                         (username,first_name,last_name,
                          email,password,password2,) 
                      VALUES 
                         (:username,:first_name,:last_name,
                          :email,:password,:password2,)");
```

Note the 2 TRAILING COMMA!

However you are not actually looking for any errors so it may have gone unnoticed by you.

As it is possible for all PDO methods to return errors, or throw PDOException if configured to do so, it is always a good idea to look for them, like this

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users 
                         (username,first_name,last_name,
                          email,password,password2) 
                      VALUES 
                         (:username,:first_name,:last_name,
                          :email,:password,:password2)");
if ( $stmt === false) {
    print_r( $db->error_info();
    exit;
}
```